# Angular 2/4 communicate with a third party library

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using simple-peer js for creating a video chat , the problem is that it is a third party library and it does not communicate to the angular system such as angular does not track property binding changes etc. here is the code

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('myVideo') myVideo:any;

  texttoken :string;

  targetpeer: any;
  peer: any;
  n = <any>navigator;

  ngOnInit() {


    let video = this.myVideo.nativeElement;
    let peerx: any;
    let jsonToken:any;
    this.n.getUserMedia = (this.n.getUserMedia || this.n.webkitGetUserMedia || this.n.mozGetUserMedia || this.n.msGetUserMedia);
    this.n.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true}, function(stream) {
    peerx = new SimplePeer ({
      initiator: location.hash === '#init',
      trickle: false,
      stream:stream
    })

    peerx.on('signal', function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
      jsonToken = JSON.stringify(data);
      this.targetpeer = data;
    })

    peerx.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('Recieved message:' + data);
    })

    peerx.on('stream', function(stream) {
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
    })

    }, function(err){
    console.log('Failed to get stream', err);
    });


    setTimeout(() => {
      this.peer = peerx;
      this.texttoken = jsonToken;
      console.log(this.peer);
    }, 1000);

  }         
}
```

so the only thing I need is to get the data from  `peerx.on('signal'` call back , and I need to get delayed data sometimes, as you can see I only able to get data after 1 second (see the timeOut function I'm getting JsonToken), the only solution I could think of is to create an infinite loop to get updated data from there every x seconds , do you have any other better ideas? how do you handle third party libs in angular 2/4? Thank You

Comment: Why can't you put the settimeout code inside 'signal' code without any timeout code ?

Comment: it does not do the two way data binding for some reason, the console.log() works but anything belongs to angular does not work inside 'signal' code, it loades faster than the angular I believe coz in timeOut function it works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `peerx` is the global variable for your third party library, you have to put this before your component decorator :

```
declare var peerx: any;
```

this way, you can access all the properties of your third-party library. If you have some time to lose, you can even write the definition file for Typescript, meaning that your IDE will have an autocompletion on it (and you will need to `import` it instead of `declare` it)

Comment: I did `declare var SimplePeer: any;` and peerx is the ref to that , should I still do it for peerx as well?

Comment: I don't see any simplePeer in your code, is that the code you're talking about ?

Comment: yes its there : `peerx = new SimplePeer ({
      initiator: location.hash === '#init',
      trickle: false,
      stream:stream
    })`  the SimplePeer is already declared the way you suggested

Comment: Then it should be okay, you should have access to the library ! Do you have any error when you try?

Comment: no error, but I now I as was talking the issue I realized that it might be that the problem is that it is asynchronous function the `getUserMedia` is a promise , that is why it works inside timeout coz it is delayed, but still my two way data binding does not work , i cant get data from there in a normal way :(